# How are before_script/afters_script executed in relation to the script commands?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I understand what the [before_script](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script) does. It executes commands to run before a job's commands get executed.
But how does that actually work under the hood?

Is it one "entity" that runs all the commands defined in the `before_script` `script` and `after_script` *in the same process*?
Or are these being executed by different processes (subshells?) sequentially?

If for instance in the `before_script` a command is run that in a normal setting, running in the background, could last the duration of the `script` would that be killed once the scope of `before_script` is finished?

Answer (score 2):

They run in the same process because you can for instance use in the `script` block a variable set in `before_script` as in the following code snippet:

```
  before_script:
    - export DOCKER_IMAGE="${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/app@${CI_IMAGE_DIGEST}"
  script:
    - echo $DOCKER_IMAGE
```

This would not work if the scripts were run in different subshells.

If you want be sure the background command will not be killed, you can simply add a `wait` command.

UPDATE-1:

This simple `.gitlab-ci.yml` setup:

```
stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - echo "PID $$"
  script:
    - echo "PID $$"
  tags:
    - shell
```

prints the following output:

[image: pipeline that show same PID in before_script and script]

that confirms what I wrote before.

UPDATE-2:

The following file `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - bin/script.sh &
  script:
    - echo "End of the script block"
    - wait
  tags:
    - shell
```

where:

```
$ cat bin/script.sh 
#!/bin/bash
sleep 120
echo "End of a long script"
```

shows that the `wait` command prevents `script.sh` to be killed:

[image: pipeline with 2 minutes script plus wait command]

Comment: How does that show it is the same process? It can be the case that the environment variables are just "forwarded" to script which runs as a separate process

Comment: I added a test to give a better evidence.